# python function to pass the boolean operators and predict the survival mean with titanic dataset

Tags: python-3.x, function, prediction

I am trying to predict the survival chances of the passengers in the testing set.i was successful to predict the values with out using the function.

Dataset as follows

```
f = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Explore-AI/Public-Data/master/Data/regression_sprint/titanic_train_raw.csv')
df_clean = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Explore-AI/Public-Data/master/Data/regression_sprint/titanic_train_clean_raw.csv')
```

the expected results are below if the value is passed via function

```
survival_likelihood(df_clean,"Pclass","==","3") == 0.24
survival_likelihood(df_clean,"Age","<","15") == 0.58
```

i was able to get the output with out writing a function as per the below image

[image]

i have written the following function and am unable to get the desired results if the values is passed via function

```
 def survival_likelihood(df_clean, column_name, boolean_operator, value):
            column_name = df_clean.columns
            value = df[column_name]
            boolean_operator = [">" or "<" or "=="]
            if column_name in df_clean.columns and df_clean[column_name].dtypes != object :
                s = round(df_clean[df[column_name][boolean_operator][value]].Survived.mean(), 
            return s
```

have tried eval() method which did not help either. Looking forward for a pointer/fix for the same. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Prakash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below one works able to achieve what i want

```
 def survival_likelihood(df_clean,column_name, boolean_operator, value):
        if  boolean_operator == '<':
            s =  df_clean[df_clean[column_name]  < eval(value)] ['Survived'].mean()
            #print(boolean_operator)
        if  boolean_operator == '>':
            s =  df_clean[df_clean[column_name]  < eval(value)] ['Survived'].mean()
            #print(boolean_operator)
        if  boolean_operator == '==':
            s =  df_clean[df_clean[column_name]  == eval(value)] ['Survived'].mean()
        return s
```